# Change the subtotal amount in commerce_email_order_items

Tags: commerce

First, sorry for my poor English, and the faults you will probably found.

Globally, what I am trying to do , is to add the shipping amount into the 'base_price' component price, also labelled subtotal.

So far, it's working correctly on the site itself with the use of the hook **hook_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter().**
To give you an idea, here is the code that handle it.

```
function base_price_shipping_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter(&$components, $price, $entity) {
    // We modify $variables to "merge" base_price and shipping
if ( isset($components['base_price']) && !empty($components['base_price']) &&
    isset($components['flat_rate_expedition_internationale']) && !empty($components['flat_rate_expedition_internationale'])) {
    // We calculate the new price with included expedition
    $price_with_shipping_amount = $components['base_price']['price']['amount'] +
        $components['flat_rate_expedition_internationale']['price']['amount'];
    // We format this price with the used currency
    $price_with_shipping_formatted = commerce_currency_format($price_with_shipping_amount, $components['base_price']['price']['currency_code']);
    // We update the display of base_price component with the new price
    $components['base_price']['price']['amount'] = $price_with_shipping_amount;
    $components['base_price']['formatted_price'] = $price_with_shipping_formatted;
    // We unset the display of shipping
    //unset($components['flat_rate_expedition_internationale']);
}
}
```

Now the problem is to do the same thing with the token [commerce-order:commerce-email-order-items].
I know it's generated with commerce_email_order_items() and by commerce_email_prepare_table() specially.
But I don't get to understand how to make it work, or where to make the change.

**Directly and overide the function commerce_email_prepare_table() ?**
It will probably be around the ligne 174 in the commerce_email.module file :

```
$data = $wrapper->commerce_order_total->data->value();
 if (!empty($data['components'])) {

   foreach ($data['components'] as $key => &$component) {

     if ($data['components'][$key]['name'] == 'base_price') {
    $rows[] = array(
      'data' => array(
        ' ',
        array('data' => t('Subtotal:'), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: right;')),
        array('data' => number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($data['components'][$key]['price']['amount'], $currency_code), 2), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: left;')),
      )
    );
  }
```

**Another possibility is to change the amount of the 'base_price' component, not on a formatted level (which just change it before display), but at the "root", for real.** I don't know if I am clear enough.
But after days of research and try to understood the Price API, I still don't get it, and which hook or function to use :
http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21price%21commerce_price.module/7

Which way do you think is the best ?
Thank you for reading.
Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after re-examining the code of the commerce_email.module, I had an epiphany, and finally get it.

Here is the code before my change (starting line 169) :

```
$data = $wrapper->commerce_order_total->data->value();
  if (!empty($data['components'])) {

foreach ($data['components'] as $key => &$component) {

  if ($data['components'][$key]['name'] == 'base_price') {
    $rows[] = array(
      'data' => array(
        ' ',
        array('data' => t('Subtotal:'), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: right;')),
        array('data' => number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($data['components'][$key]['price']['amount'], $currency_code), 2), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: left;')),
      )
    );
  }
```

And now with my change :

```
$data = $wrapper->commerce_order_total->data->value();
 if (!empty($data['components'])) {
  foreach ($data['components'] as $key => &$component) {
         if ($data['components'][$key]['name'] == 'flat_rate_expedition_internationale' || $data['components'][$key]['name'] == 'flat_rate_expedition_outremerre' ) {
            $amount_expedition = $data['components'][$key]['price']['amount'];
          }

  }
  foreach ($data['components'] as $key => &$component) {
      if ($data['components'][$key]['name'] == 'base_price') {

          $amount_base_price = $data['components'][$key]['price']['amount'];
            if (isset($amount_expedition)) {
                $amount_base_price += $amount_expedition;
            }
          $rows[] = array(
              'data' => array(
                  ' ',
                  array('data' => t('Prix HT :'), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: 10px')),
                  array('data' => number_format(commerce_currency_amount_to_decimal($amount_base_price, $currency_code), 2), 'style' => array('font-weight: bold; text-align: right;')),
              )
          );
      }
```

It's not a great solution, and I will try to make a full module, to select dynamically the components to add to the base_price.
Until then, this will do the job.